# Highcharts, multiple scatter series dates not working with stacking

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with a column-range as high & low dates & 2 scatter series with additional dates as points. If I only have 1 scatter series, everything works fine, but when I add the 2nd. scatter series it screws up the dates for the 1st. series. Also, if I remove the **stacking: 'normal'** then everything works fine.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Here's my [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2ughpvh/10/) showing the issue.

```
{
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'scatter 1',
    color: 'red',
    data: [new Date('2016-06-01').getTime(), new Date('2017-06-01').getTime(), new Date('2018-06-01').getTime()],
    marker: { radius: 5 }
}, {
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'scatter 2',
    color: 'blue',
    data: [new Date('2014-03-01').getTime(), new Date('2015-03-01').getTime(), new Date('2016-03-01').getTime()],
    marker: { radius: 5 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `stacking: 'normal'` within series instead of `plotOptions` .This is so because it is effecting `scatter` type

```
series: [
     {
      name: 'Office Manager',
      data: [{y: 0, low: new Date('2014-01-01').getTime(), high: new Date('2015-01-01').getTime()},
      {y: 0, low: new Date('2015-01-01').getTime(), high: new Date('2016-01-01').getTime()},
      {y: 0, low: new Date('2016-01-01').getTime(), high: new Date('2017-01-01').getTime()}],
      stacking: 'normal'
  },  {       
      name: 'CAD',
      data: [{y: 0, low: new Date('2015-01-01').getTime(), high: new Date('2016-01-01').getTime()},
      {y: 0, low: new Date('2016-01-01').getTime(), high: new Date('2017-01-01').getTime()},
      {y: 0, low: new Date('2017-01-01').getTime(), high: new Date('2018-01-01').getTime()}],
      stacking: 'normal'
  }, {
      name: 'STUFF',
      data: [{y: 0, low: new Date('2016-01-01').getTime(), high: new Date('2017-01-01').getTime()},
      {y: 0, low: new Date('2017-01-01').getTime(), high: new Date('2018-01-01').getTime()},
      {y: 0, low: new Date('2018-01-01').getTime(), high: new Date('2019-01-01').getTime()}],
      stacking: 'normal'
  },

    {
        type: 'scatter',
        name: 'scatter 1',
        color: 'red',
        data: [new Date('2016-06-01').getTime(), new Date('2017-06-01').getTime(), new Date('2018-06-01').getTime()],
        marker: { radius: 5 }
    }, {
        type: 'scatter',
        name: 'scatter 2',
        color: 'blue',
        data: [new Date('2014-03-01').getTime(), new Date('2015-03-01').getTime(), new Date('2016-03-01').getTime()],
        marker: { radius: 5 }
    }

    ]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2ughpvh/11/)